# How to Setup Power BI Custom connector as web based application?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource, power-apps-custom-connector

We are developing a web-based application for our database. We want to create a custom connector for Power BI to load data from the database using the web-based application.
We want to develop an m query to authenticate like the below image when clicking on sign in option it will go our web application in the default browser and authenticate.

[image]

Can someone help us with the authentication setup code sample in m query language, since this is new to us?
We tried web.contents, web.browsercontents not so sure about this connector topic.